# Ansible command line limit parameter

Tags: ansible

While calling Ansible playbook through command line what do following command `outer:local:dns` will  search for or will perform ?

`ansible-playbook --limit outer:local:dns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you could just google it.
The value that is passed to `--limit` is the hostname(s) or host group(s) that an Ansible playbook will be applied to.
You can [read more about the pattern syntax here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns).

Answer (score 2):

The command `outer:local:dns` is a pattern referring to multiple groups in the inventory.
Coupling this pattern with `--limit` means that the playbook will be executed for the group `outer`, the group `local` and the group `dns`.

For more information about ansible pattern, see this [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns).